# Can someone identify these shower stems & handles?

Tags: plumbing, repair, shower, faucet, bathtub

Looking to replace the shower stem and handle for a family members tub. Attached are the photos for the stems they have. Can someone help me identify what type of stems they are, so I purchase the correct ones? I believe there are two types of stem designs, Pfister and Gerber? If yes, can anyone help me identify which one these are based on the photos below? Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm curious, why did you make "shower stem" and "handle replacement" all upper case?

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be a Price Pfister tub/shower valve.

**Note 1**- there are wayyyy more manufacturers/brands than just P.P. and Gerber. And each manufacturer has many (many many) different styles/models/types.

**Note 2**- it is not just the "stem" that the manufacturer/brand (and style/model/type) applies to; the whole valve assembly is manufacturer/brand-specific.

**Note 3**- while stems and trim are generally manufacturer/brand-specific and not interchangeable, this particular brand and model is pretty common (at least in the U.S.) and replacement parts are widely available from both the original maker (P.P.) and from others.

**Note 4**- I *highly* recommend that you remove the stems and bring them with you when you go to the plumbing shop to get the parts you need.

Comment: If you are handy enough to remove the stems, you are capable of rebuilding stems that are still in good condition. All the repair parts (bibb washers, packing, diverter washer) are readily available; this would save some $$.

Comment: I figured the best approach was to disassemble and take to the store to get the correct replacement. Since I have to shut off the water supply, I was trying to purchase ahead of time so I would have it ready to replace that way the house wouldn't be without water for too long. Once I confirm the type of stems, I was going to purchase one of these rebuild kits to repair. https://www.lowes.com/pd/Danco-3-Handle-Metal-Tub-Shower-Repair-Kit-For-Price-Pfister/1092415

Comment: Yup, that's the kit. Be careful not to apply any shear (up/down/left/right) stress when removing the valves with that special deep socket; only rotational force. I use large Channellock type pliers on the socket, to turn it. Note also that the kit comes with replacement valve *seats*, which require a special different wrench that does not appear to be included in the kit; the seats don't necessarily need to be replaced...

Comment: Any other tools outside of the large channel locks that would be helpful for this type of job?

Comment: Utility knife and putty knife to slice through old caulking under flanges (flanges are technically called *escutcheons*); hammer and flat-head screwdriver (or narrow chisel) to carefully break out mortar/grout/tile that might be in the way of valve removal; silicone plumber's grease to lube up... well, everything; phillips screwdriver for handle screws; medium to large pipe wrench (in case Channelocks are insufficient). Hmmm...

Comment: Also once I do remove the stem and valve assembly what are the key identifiers I should look for to determine the style / manufacturer? Is it visual? Do I have to measure a specific feature? How do i know if they are Pfister or some other style?

Comment: If the valves are original, they will likely be stamped "PP" on the brass valve body. The biggest clue is if the size and appearance is the same, and the new valves are able to be screwed into the wall chassis, the thread on the part in the wall is specific by maker.  An early clue is if the new knobs fit the splines on the old stems (the stem spline size/type is pretty specific by brand). Your picture makes me 99% certain it is Price Pfister; it is a pretty common unit in the US...